# @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor not generating .json report

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I moved from `'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'` to `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`.
And missed the json report generated on execution.

Kindly please let me know how to generated the `.json` report and attached screenshot for failure test.

**Package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": " npx cypress run --env TAGS=\"@home\""
  },    
 "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.1.0",
        "cypress": "^12.3.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.1.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.1.5",
        "cypress-xpath": "^2.0.1"
      },
      "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
        "stepDefinitions": "cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.js",
        "commonPath": "cypress/e2e/common/**/*.cy.js",
        "filterSpecs": true,
        "omitFiltered": true,
        "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
        "cucumberJson": {
          "generate": true,
          "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber_report",
          "filePrefix": "",
          "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
        }
      }
    }
```

**cypress.config.js**

```
    const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
    const createBundler = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor');
    const addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin =
      require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin;
    const createEsbuildPlugin =
      require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild').createEsbuildPlugin;
    
    
    
    module.exports = defineConfig({
      defaultCommandTimeout: 5000,
      numTestsKeptInMemory: 0,
      viewportWidth: 1360,
      viewportHeight: 768,
      env: {
        username: 'xxxxxxx',
        password: 'xxxxxxxx'
       },
  

    e2e: {
         // Integrate @bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor plugin.
        async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
          const bundler = createBundler({
            plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
          });

      // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
      on('file:preprocessor', bundler);
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      return config;
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.feature',
},
})
```

Answer (score 1):

According [the release notes](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/releases/tag/v16.0.0), since v16.0.0 cucumber-json-formatter is replaced with native components.
This means that you should place configuration options either in .cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json or package.json like so:

```
{
  "json": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

The documentation about JSON reports is [HERE](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/json-report.md).

Answer (score 0):

According to this [doc](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/json-report.md), download [cucumber-json-formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/json-formatter) and then setup your `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` JSON report like this:

```json
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    ...
    "json": {
        "enabled": true,
        "formatter": "formatter/path/here",
        "output": "report/path/here"
    }
}
```

In addition, by default, it searches your `PATH` if you don't provide a `"formatter"`.

Screenshots on failure are also attached by default.